# Unable to Replicate an ANN Using the Output from Predict Function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I’m working on constructing an ANN. I first used the Predict function with the method “Neural Network” to determine the structure according to my data.

This is the given output of the structure:

[image]

[image]

Based on the output, I have understood the NetArrayLayer should be linked to the NetChain, however, I am unable to find a way to link my NetChain with the NetArrayLayer, without receiving the below error.

[image]

Is anyone able to advise on this?

Comment: NetArrayLayer is used to provide a learnable input to some other operations. The structure you have is a chain so it has one input and one output. Where do you want to connect the array to?